# How to set type for createApp(App) function in vuejs 3?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I am using vue3 with firebase, on typescript.

```
// main.ts
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import './registerServiceWorker'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'
import { auth } from './firebase'

// eslint-disable-next-line
let app: any

auth.onAuthStateChanged(() => {
  if (!app) {
    app = createApp(App)
      .use(store)
      .use(router)
      .mount('#app')
  }
})
```

What type should I set to 'app' variable? I tried App, typeof App but it failed.

Comment: how did it fail? isn't the editor providing a hint of the detected type along with the fail you mention?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`createApp` returns an [App](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-next/blob/0d0970f9cd337f66992359a75a4126c1fdc9f865/packages/runtime-core/src/apiCreateApp.ts#L19) instance. Since you already have an `App` imported, you need to rename the type while importing. But notice `app.mount` returns a [different type](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-next/blob/0d0970f9cd337f66992359a75a4126c1fdc9f865/packages/runtime-core/src/apiCreateApp.ts#L28-L31), you can't chain it after `createApp` without changing the type:

```
import { createApp, App as Application } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
// other imports

let app: Application 

auth.onAuthStateChanged(() => {
  if (!app) {
    app = createApp(App)
    app.use(store)
    app.use(router)
    app.mount('#app')
  }
})
```

Comment: Wow great! I didn't know that mount functions returns a different type. Thank you.